# Python not enough armugents for format string

Tags: python, string, integer, format

I try to open a specific page on google. Like the user types in a search keyword and the specific site (e.g. "2") and then it gives the results.

So, the search is generally working. Now I tried to put the specific site in.

```
class Google:
    @classmethod
    def search(self, search, sites):
        page = requests.get("http://www.google.de/search?q=%s&start=%i 0"%search %sites)
        [...]


class Menu:
    @classmethod
    def start_menu(self):
        begriff = raw_input("Bitte gib deinen Suchbegriff ein: ")
        seiten = raw_input("Wie viele Seiten willst du öffnen?: ")
        Google.search(begriff, seiten)


Menu.start_menu()
```

Why isn't it working?

The error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Thank you!

Comment: try with `" % (search,sites)` in the end, no double %.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yea, thank you!

Comment: BTW: [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 1):

String formatting takes one argument as tuple. You should replace

```
 %search %sites
```

with

```
% (search, sites)
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply multiple values, use a *tuple*, not multiple `%` operators:

```
"http://www.google.de/search?q=%s&start=%i 0" % (search, sites)
```

What happens otherwise is that only `search` is applied, and that is not enough for the *two* slots in the string (the `% sites` would be applied to the result of `"..." % search` if that was successful).

Next, you'll get an error that `sites` is not a number:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

because `raw_input()` returns a *string*, not a number. Use `%s` to interpolate the string:

```
"http://www.google.de/search?q=%s&start=%s 0" % (search, sites)
```

You probably need to remove that stray `' 0'` at the end too.

Comment: ah, thank you. That makes sense. Now I got this error: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: @Lucas: well, if `sites` is not a number, don't use `%i` or `%d` (`%i` is an alias for `%d`), or convert `sites` to a number first.